# $many_many relation in summary fields

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have two classes with a `$many_many` and `$belongs_many_many` relation between them. I tried to define `$summary_fields` in the class that contains the `$many_many` to display the relation between the classes but that column ('Column2.Column2') displays blank results. How do I set `$summary_fields` to display this data correctly?

Here is my code

```
class Table1 extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Column1' => 'Varchar(32)'
    );

    private static $many_many = array (
        'Column2' => 'Table2'
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array (
        'Column1' => 'Column 1',
        'Column2.Column2' => 'Column 2'
    );
}

class Table2 extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Column2' => 'Varchar(32)'
    );

    private static $belongs_many_many = array (
        'Column1' => 'Table1'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is a `$many_many` relationship or a `$has_many` relationship can be linked to multiple objects. We cannot put a `$many_many` or `$has_many` into `$summary_fields` as a single row as the GridField does not know how to display more than one item.

For example, say we have `Columns.Title` where `Columns` is a `$many_many` relationship on the current object. If we have three `Columns` objects linked to the current object, the system doesn't know to display the Title of the three columns.

What we can do is create a function to return a string displaying the data that we want to display.

The following code is written for Silverstripe 3.

```
class Table1 extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Title' => 'Varchar(32)',
    ];

    private static $many_many = [
        'Columns' => 'Table2',
    ];

    private static $field_labels = [
        'ColumnsString' => 'Columns',
    ];

    private static $summary_fields = [
        'Title',
        'ColumnsString',
    ];

    public function ColumnsString()
    {
        return implode(', ', $this->Columns()->column('Title'));
    }
}

class Table2 extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Title' => 'Varchar(32)',
    ];

    private static $belongs_many_many = [
        'Columns' => 'Table1',
    ];
}
```

Comment: all 'ColumnsString' appear in same row of 'Title'.  How do I put every 'ColumnsString' in separate rows with repeating 'Title'?